# JSON file not working on my Music Player in android

Tags: android, json

When I enter the following link to my JSON file in the code it works.

http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/music.json

When I enter the other link instead of the one above

https://api.myjson.com/bins/kznq7

My application runs perfectly fine but when I play any music in it. I get the error shown below.

Kindly assist me with the issue. What is wrong with it.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: what error exactly ?

Comment: Kindly post logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one Json you have \u0026, at the other '&'.
This is the first that comes to my mind, from the little information you give me.
Example, "Jazz \u0026 Blues" vs "Jazz & Blues"

Comment: Ok, now you have "Jazz and Blues", instead of "Jazz & Blues". What is exactly stopping you from fixing this? Make the values exactly the same. Stop changing '&' with \u0026 or the word 'and'. Or anything else.

Comment: Whenever I upload my JSON file on the online storage it itself converts the '&' into '\u0026'. How can I avoid that the website that I am using to upload my JSON file is [Storage for JSON] (myjson.com/)

Comment: Does the same happen when you use the json that is working?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't but I don't have the access to the same storage now. So I can't use it or edit the file. I need some place to store my file from where I can access it and I am confused about it.

Comment: Can you, just for testing, hardcode it in your app? Or perhaps add it as asset? Or put the file on FTP server that runs on your PC? Or upload it to any free file hosting. Im not sure how I can help you more. All you give me is that one json works, the other does not, and the only difference I see is that symbol getting changed.